# What are the latest Ubuntu certified laptops using the official Ubuntu image?

Tags: 16.04, laptop, hardware-certification

The [list of latest (16.04) Ubuntu certified laptops using the official Ubuntu image](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?query=&category=Laptop&level=Certified&release=16.04%20LTS) is empty.
The only certified laptops come with pre-installed image.

What are the latest Ubuntu certified laptops using the official (downloadable) Ubuntu image?

Thanks.

* Please do not mark as duplicate of the general question about certification. This is question is more specific.

Comment: @user535733, your link is for pre-installed. The question is about the official, downloadable, version.